# Greenhouse gas emission calculator

Tags: modeling

I want to calculate green gas emission from motorcycles using fuel use and run a simulation for 10 years later. To get the fuel use the distance covered per day will be divided by the total number of liters of fuel per day. Variables such as engine size and fuel type (petrol or diesel) should be incorporated as well. what software is available and recognized by IPCC to carry this out ? The software must run on spark OS preferably windows, the cost must be less than 500 USD.

Comment: What other features does the simulation require? Do you require an interactive simulation where you can change parameters on the fly? Do you need a plotting library in the program that allows you to show the results of the simulation graphically?

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! Does it suffice if it's running on SparkOS – or must it run on something else? :) Also: how much are you willing to spend if it comes to paid software? Please [edit] your question and fill the gaps – so we are able to give fitting recommendations. Thanks!

Comment: And, do you already have the hardware to perform the measurements? If not, see https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/  In my experience, most hardware comes with accompanying software. This will, for instance, determine the data format, which might, in turn, influence your choice of simulation software.

Comment: @karel It does not have to be an interactive simulation as the  parameters would have to be constant, I am only looking to quantify total emissions. displaying of the results of the simulation would be bonus without having to export it to another tool.

Comment: @Mawg am not using any hardware for the measurements for emissions. It will be based on the fuel usage per motorcycle.

Comment: That tells you how much fuel you are using. Are you trusting the vehicle manufacturers for the emission data? Have you already forgotten https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volkswagen_emissions_scandal and   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diesel_emissions_scandal    ??!!   Also, different vehicles of the same year/model will have different emission after a while. If you want any sort of accuracy, then you will need hardware.